# Finding perspective transformation between two planes

Tags: opencv, perspectivecamera

I have a point cloud created from multiple images. I extracted a plane from it, it is also in 3d co-ordinate system, this implies I have the plane equation of that plane. But in none of the original images the plane has ortho-normal view, that is the plane is not parallel to the viewing plane. But, as I have the plane's 3d cloud, I want to project it in XY plane, that is I want to make the plane parallel to the viewing plane and create an image from it. What is the algorithm or function to do it in C++/OpenCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want to do, but  these may help you, I did this with a chessboard:

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> not_a_rect_shape;  // In this vector you should save the x,y coordinates of your 3D rect  

// the not_a_rect_shapecoordinates are from you source frame 



// Define the destination image
            quad = cv::Mat::zeros(300, 220, CV_8UC3);  // the size is important, it depends on your application, I have to say that 300x220 isn't always the right one. you have to give more infomations!! 


// these will be the parallel plane vector of point 
quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
            quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(quad.cols, 0));
            quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(quad.cols, quad.rows));
            quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,quad.rows));


transformationMatrix= cv::getPerspectiveTransform(not_a_rect_shape, quad_pts);// this is you transformation matirx 

cv::warpPerspective(src, quad, transformationMatrix,quad.size(),CV_INTER_LINEAR,cv::BORDER_ISOLATED); // the flags could change
```

now quad frame should be that what you're looking for!
I hope it helps

Comment: Well, I have used it when I actually have an image of a known rectangular shape(i.e. playing card). From that image, I can get exact cv::Point2fs. But, what I have now is 3d world coordinate of the image, there are negative (x,y)s too. So, at first I have to get the 2d image points where the plane is parallel to view plane(I don't have such image beforehand). So, I want 2d image coordinates(which doesn't exist beforehand) from 3d world coordinate.

Comment: Putting it consicely, I want to project 3d world coordinate into 2d image coordinate, where I will get the ortho-normal view(object is straight facing and upright/parallel to the plane of view) of the object

Comment: could you upload your image  so I can understand it better

Comment: Well, with your suggestion, I have found an answer. Though, the object I have is not a perfect rectangle, I calculated convex hull around it, then again,I calculated minimum quadrilateral around it manually. Then, I used the four vertices in the way you stated above. Thanks.